# Android Gen Folder disapear when export signed APK

Tags: android, export, apk, signed, r.java-file

Big issue.

Everytime I try to export a signed APK using eclipse, at the last action, when I click "finish" the content of my gen folder suddenly disapear so the R file cannot be resolved anymore and I finaly get a error message: "errors occured during the build" due to the R file missing.

Lets clean all of this, get my R file back, retry... but same error as well.

Moreover, I can't use "ant release" to get my signed apk because the previous developper used a key alias containing an accent: "é" so that ant produce an error skipping the caracter when trying to use the alias.
Eclipse can manage this accent problem, but can't build for the previous reason.

My goal is to publish an update of this app, so it seems that I have to use the same alias.

What should I do?

thanks

Comment: have you tried switching off automatic builds?

Comment: I tried, but didnt change anything